# mysqli_query string less long

Tags: php, mysql

I have just started to learn MySQL and its syntax. My question is:

Are there some options to do this in a more readable way and use less quotes and escaping slashes? It seems to me 'a little stupid' how it is written so far. And also I think this is the problem why `mysqli_escape_string()` isn't doing what I expect:

```
mysqli_set_charset($connection, 'utf8');
$string = "INSERT INTO pass_words(site_name,user_id,pass_id,email,question,answer) VALUE ("
                .
                ' \' '.$site.' \' '
                . ','.
                ' \' '
                .$acc_name.' \' '
                . ','.
                ' \' '
                .$pass.' \' '
                . ','.
                ' \' '
                .$email.' \' '
                . ','.
                ' \' '
                .$question.' \' '
                . ','
                .' \' '
                . ''.$answer.' \' '.')' ;
if($query = mysqli_query($connection, mysqli_escape_string($connection, $string))){
    echo '<div style="color: #00FF99; margin: 0 0 20px 0;"> The Account Information has been added correctly.</div>';
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way using SET.

```
$string = "INSERT INTO pass_words SET site_name = '$site', user_id = '$acc_name', pass_id = '$pass', email = '$email', question = '$question', answer = '$answer'";
```

Comment: this worked but i needed to put manually for all variables - $connection->real_escape_string(), before using the $string. 

thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to make a compact but unreadable mess.

- Make your SQL query as lofty as you want.
- Use `?` placeholders and [parameter binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).
- And use ***any*** wrapper function for parameter binding (`mysqli` by itself is horrible to use).

Something like:

```
xyz_query("
     INSERT INTO pass_words
         (site_name, user_id, pass_id, email, question, answer)
     VALUES
         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
     ", # ↑      ↑       ↑
     [$site, $acc_name, $pass, $email, $question, $answer]
);
```

Comment: This helped me, too. Thanks for the answer and the advice.

Comment: Is binding a better practise than just including the variables in a string? Is there any benefit?

Comment: @James111 It's both prettier to look at, and more reslient against arbitrary values (which is what makes it more secure). See http://i.stack.imgur.com/M7PXp.png and [Why shouldn't I use mysql\_\* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20767765)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = "INSERT INTO `pass_words`(`site_name`, `user_id`, `pass_id`, `email`, `question`, `answer`) 
VALUES('$site', '$acc_name', '$pass', '$email', '$question', '$answer')";
```